# Purely algebraic areas of number theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

So the question is undoubtedly naive. But what I ask is whether there are any active areas of number theory which exclusively use methods from algebra (why you would desire such a restriction being another matter)?

Thank you!

Comment: Algebra is closely related to a great part of the number theory. For example, the algebraic factors : A number of the form $n^2-1$ with $n>2$ is never a prime because it has the non-trivial algebraic factors $n-1$ and $n+1$. The cyclotomic polynomials are another nice connection between the two topics.

Comment: As it happens @Peter, I was at a talk last week where cyclotomic polynomials were approached using combinatorial methods so even those are not exempt.

Answer (score 2):

As a researcher in algebraic number theory, I cannot say that I know of any active areas which solely use algebra. I constantly come across statements which use some knowledge of differential geometry or complex analysis (eg L functions) or topology (eg linear algebraic groups).

Research topics should be approached from many different methods so if only algebra is being used then either it is solved and therefore uninteresting (in which case generalisations should be considered and may then use other areas) or the researchers are being naive. So, whilst a particular group may attack the problem using algebra, it is highly probable that another group may be able to get results using other methods.

However, the lines of what exactly algebraic number theory is are blurred and maybe there is some area (that I am not aware of) that is as yet untouched by other methods.